# PIG: script never ending

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera, oozie

I have a coordinator which contains one workflow, with several "PIG forks". Each "PIG fork" is the execution of the same PIG script with different parameters.

Such coordinator consumes all resources available on the cluster, because PIG scripts have lot of data to proceed. Now here is the problem.

Sometimes, the coordinator successfully terminates in two hours. Sometimes, it never ends.

In this second case, PIG logs are:

```
2016-05-19 04:14:08,884 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl  - Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1460732649780_25701_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
...
2016-05-19 07:40:38,492 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl  - Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1460732649780_25701_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
```

Such message then repeats indefinitely in every forked PIG scripts... and YARN seems frozen (it can't allocate new containers).

Do you have solutions to address such issue ?

Comment: FYI, coordinator contains only one workflow, It might be the case that many instances of the workflow are running depending on the startTime, eneTime and frequency.

Comment: Can you provide more info what is happening when jobs are not completing? Does the resources available, multiple workflows started or what?

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post. Thanks!